# Unable to create socket: Operation not permitted - Mac

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to run portscaner as part of my work at school. When I run the code it shows an error msg "Operation not permitted". This msg is printed directly after the OS fails to create a socket.

Notes:
1. my system is Mac OS X 10.6.8
2. in this project I'm using row socket.
3. I've written a code before the creates TCP socket and runs perfectly.

I assume this error appear because row sockets require some kind of higher privilege that my system currently has. Does anyone know how to change the privilege in my system?
Any helps is highly appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide some more details, like code examples?

Comment: Here is the eample I'm running: http://www.binarytides.com/tcp-syn-portscan-in-c-with-linux-sockets/

Comment: @XXX http://www.ae.iitm.ac.in/pipermail/ilugc/2003-October/006661.html

Answer (score 1):

The process has to have root privileges to open a raw socket.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I do that?

Comment: Either run your application as root user, or change the ownership of the binary file to root (chown root _filename_) and set `setuid` bit on that file (chmod +s _filename_) but I am not sure that the latter option is available with OSX

Comment: Thanks Sergo. It works now. What I did is typing sudo before executing the program. i.e. sudo ./execfile

Answer (score 0):

Some time another socket is running under the same port